# vlad the deployer vlad:start_app with passenger issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, vlad-deployer

I'm trying to deploy a rails app using vlad the deployer.

I'm using nginx and passenger.

I have an issue with the vlad:start_app task.

When I deploy I get the following issue

```
touch: cannot touch `/var/www/mysite.com/releases/20100623130302/tmp/restart.txt': No such file or directory
rake aborted!
execution failed with status 1: ssh mysite.com touch /var/www/mysite.com/releases/20100623130302/tmp/restart.txt
```

The issue is obvious in that the 20100623130302 in releases does not exist.

I would rather use the following task but cant override the default vlad:start_app task by placing this in my config/deploy.rb file.

```
namespace :vlad do

  desc 'Restart Passenger'
    remote_task :start_app do
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

end
```

Any help appreciated. The options I though of are to either get the default vlad task to work or someway to override the default vlad task.

Answer (score 0):

`RAILS_ROOT/Rakefile` is the file.

Comment: I've already tried that however the vlad tasks are loaded from the vlad gem like...
    begin
      require "vlad"
      Vlad.load(:app => :passenger, :scm => "git")
    rescue LoadError => e
      puts "Unable to load Vlad #{e}."
    end
Also remote_task is something loaded with vlad so tasks cant be defined using remote_task until vlad is loaded at which point come the existing vlad:start_app task also!

Answer (score 0):

To override a task you have to remove the previous one first as defining the same task again just creates a second task that will run after the first one.

Here's an example from the [vlad website](http://hitsquad.rubyforge.org/vlad/doco/faq_txt.html) how to replace a task:

```
namespace :vlad do
  # Clear existing update task so that we can redefine instead of adding to it.
  Rake.clear_tasks('vlad:update')

  remote_task :update, :roles => :app do
    #custom update stuff
  end
end
```